# Efficiently packing and unpacking function arguments in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have some R code where I'm starting to get too many arguments in my functions, like this

```
f<-function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,...){
  #do stuff with a,b,c,d,e,f,g
  return(list(q=q,r=r,s=s,...))
}
```

I was thinking of collapsing arguments into lists of related parameters and then extracting out the parameters from the lists inside the function. This is annoying though since I have to use a lot of boilerplate code

```
list_of_params<-list(a=a,b=b,...)
f<-function(list_of_params){
  a<-list_of_params[["a"]]
  b<-list_of_params[["b"]]
  c<-list_of_params[["c"]]
  ...
  #do stuff with a,b,c,...
  return(list(q=q,r=r,s=s,...))
}
```

I was thinking about using something like `list2env` to automatically extract the variables from the list into the environment of the function. Does anyone have opinions about whether that is a reasonable approach? I read somewhere that using `assign` is a bad idea and this seems similar. My proposed function would look like this:

```
f<-function(list_of_params){
  list2env(list_of_params, envir=as.environment(-1)) #-1 means current environment
  #do stuff with a,b,c...
  return(list(q=q,r=r,s=s,...))
}
```

I have never used `assign()` or `list2env()` before. I am concerned they may have treacherous pitfalls I should watch out for, in the same manner as `attach()`. Is the use of `list2env()` here appropriate? If not, what is the appropriate use of this function?

Comment: Why do you need so many arguments?  Keep it simple.

Comment: I agree with Richard. Do you really need to do something with/to *all* of those arguments in a function? It seems like you should be writing small functions that accept a list as an argument and do one or two quick things with a small number of the list components. Think of the way an `lm` object works - it's just a list, but when I use `predict` or `summary` on it I don't want to pass in individual components... I just pass in the model object (AKA the list).

Comment: I agree with gregor that this is very broad and difficult to answer without context

Comment: I think `assign` has more in the way of "common misuses" rather than "treacherous pitfalls". When people use `assign()` because they are constructing variable names with `paste` it means they should be using a list. When people use `assign()` to drop things in the global environment from a function, it means they should be returning the object from their function instead.

Comment: I agree with rawr agreeing with Gregor agreeing with me.

Comment: It sounds like you all are recommending I stick with the second function (with the list_of_params as function argument and the explicit unpacking)? The context is variational inference for graphical models. The parameters are the sufficient statistics for nodes in the graphical model. Perhaps a simpler version of my question is, "Is there ever a good reason to use list2env() inside a function?"

Comment: I think our joint recommendation is that you shouldn't unpack at all. And moreover that you think you need to unpack *so many arguments*, it probably an indication that your functions are trying to do too much - you should break them into smaller functions.

Comment: As to *Is there ever a good reason to use list2env() inside a function?*, I'm sure there is, but that's far too broad and opiniony to be a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: As I said in another thread the other day, the problem with `attach` is *what it does* not *how it does it*. Using `attach()` on your list will get you what you are asking for. We just think you're asking the wrong question. `fortunes::fortune(379)`.

Comment: These are the best kind of question, but unfortunately they are often times not adequately addressed. After all the benevolent words spend, we still don't know what could be the problem with the proposed solution using `list2env`.

Comment: The zeallot R package may be useful here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zeallot/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A long list of parameters is probably a code-smell.
The easiest thing to do is to stop, and think about what type of object that should encapsulate your parameters.  It's probably not just a simple list.

Another option is if many of the function parameters are held fixed in terms of procedural or lexical scope.  Then you could use the fact that [functions are R are closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures).  Example:

```
make_f <- function(object, params){
   e <- calculate_e(object, params)
   f <- calculate_f(object, params)
   g <- calculate_g(object, params)
   f<-function(a,b,c,d,...){
        #do stuff with a,b,c,d,e,f,g
        return(list(q=q,r=r,s=s,...))
   }
   return(f)
}
```